# Mock server in java

Tags: java, spring, mockserver

I want to use mock server in my bisuness logic to mock a response from external service, any idea how to do it, I'm using spring boot and java.

Here is a simple scenario, I want to retrieve data from external service, but the api of this external service is not created yet, and I want to mock the response with the MockServer https://www.mock-server.com/

Comment: Google 'wiremock'. It has good integration with Spring.

Comment: Google Mock server + Spring.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to generate mocked version of your service if you have the openAPI specification (swagger) of your external service,
You can use the **https://app.swaggerhub.com/apis/jamesdbloom/mock-server-openapi/5.14.x#/expectation/put_mockserver_openapi** Endpoint so that mockserver generate automatically mocked responses based on the specification
hope it helps